# small problem in the article ()

Tags: templates, template-tags

WP 5.4
Theme masonic

I try to show the numer of comments in each article
 it'as ok (see the picture)
but on the next line, itshow   ()

I don't know why !?!?

---

the code in the file template-tags is:

```
echo '<div class="entry-author vcard author fa fa-user"><a class="url fn n" href="' . esc_url(get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'))) . '">' . esc_html(get_the_author()) . '</a></div>';

// Show number of comments
echo '<div>(' . comments_number( '(0) ', '(1)', '(%)' ) . ')</div>';
```

[image: article 1]

[image: picture 2]

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues at play here.

First, you've got two sets of parentheses:

```
           ↓ Here                 ↓ And Here
echo '<div>(' . comments_number( '(0) ', '(1)', '(%)' ) . ')</div>';
```

You only want one.

Second, you're trying to concatenate a string (`.`) with a function, `comments_number()`, that echoes. This results in `comments_number()` being outut immediately, and then the rest of the string outputting after that. This is where the second `()` comes from.

To fix the issue, either remove `echo` and output like this:

```
comments_number( '<div>(0)</div>div>', '<div>(1)</div>div>', '<div>(%)</div>div>' ) . ');
```

Or use [`get_comments_number_text()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments_number_text/) which *returns* the same value:

```
echo '<div>(' . get_comments_number_text( '0', '1', '%' ) . ')</div>';
```

Note that I've also removed the redundant parentheses.